# json_encode doens't work in my Symfony2's controller

Tags: php, html, angularjs, symfony

I'm new in Symfony2 and AngularJS. I´m trying to use json_encode to show my database's content. But it doens't work. This is my controller:

```
public function catalogonewAction() 
{
  $data = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
    ->getRepository('AcmeRetroBundle:Game')->findAll(); 

  return $this->render('AcmeRetroBundle:Default:catalogonew.html.twig', 
    array('data' => json_encode($data)));}
```

This is my html.twig:

```
{% verbatim %}
<div ng-app="myApp1" ng-init="mydata = {{ list|raw }}">
<table id="sortedData">
<tr><th>T1</th><th>T2</th></tr>
<tr ng-repeat="data in mydata | filter:sortData">
 <td>{{data.nombreJuego}}</td>
 <td>{{data.description}}</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
 {% endverbatim %}
```

And my app.js:

```
angular.module('myApp1', []).
 filter('sortData', function() {
  alert('Hi');
  return out;
 });
```

When I refresh my page it is shown this:
    T1  T2
    {{data.nombreJuego}}    {{data.description}}

What is wrong?

Comment: Looks like javascript error stopped angularjs from bootstraping, check out console and add your errors output

Comment: Ask yourself what verbatim means.  Mixing angular templates and twig templates is frustrating to say the least.

Comment: Ok. I fix it. I change all the code in controller and remove verbatim. I use the InterpolateProvider.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like to pass data from back-end to an 
anuglarJS like that, it's a common to use ajax request to retrieve data.

Try to pass you data to a javascript variable that you could affect is to an object in you angular scope :

```
     <script>
           var list= {{ data }} 
     </script>     
     {% verbatim %}
           <div ng-app="myApp1" ng-init="mydata = list">
           <table id="sortedData">
            <tr><th>T1</th><th>T2</th></tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="data in mydata | filter:sortData">
              <td>{{data.nombreJuego}}</td>
              <td>{{data.description}}</td>
            </tr>
           </table>
          </div>
     {% endverbatim %}
```